# Why is my lighting not turning on after updating single pole light switch for a newer light switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, recessed-lighting

enter preformatted text hereI'm updating the light switches in my kitchen and one of the switch boxes has 2 switches: *one single pole with 3 black wires* and *one 3-way pole switch*.

I disconnected all the wires from the single pole switch and connected to the new switch. At that point I had forgotten where the third wire went on the switch and just added to the top connection. When turning the switch on none of the lights turned on and my breaker was tripped.

I tried different variations and was able to get the dinning room lighting working, BUT all of the ceiling recessed lighting are **not working**.

I changed the new switch back to the old one and now I'm not able to get the recessed lighting to turn on either.

The image shows both switches (never touched the 3 way switch)and the different wire combinations per row and its results.

Did something going to the recessed lighting break? Where should I wire the 3rd black wire?

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: A closer pic of the wiring on the switch in question and a pic of the wires going into the back of the box so we can see how they're grouped into cables would be very helpful. You can [edit] those into your question, please don't post them as an "answer".

Comment: Blind "black-box" experimentation ***is bad***. It can damage wires by overloading them, and test your breakers' ability to trip (FPE? Challenger?)  The breaker tripping was a sign you should have stopped.  Also generally, one experiments with the aim to stop at the first combination that works, right?  Well, many combinations will work *and then kill you*.  With electrical, be Tesla not Edison - think, don't spam.

Comment: @FreeMan I got a voltmeter and got a reading for the current bottom wire to be 120V. Please see photo for inside of box. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the circuit working by removing the 3 way switch's ground wire. That was causing it to trip. Thanks all!

Comment: You *need* to dig deeper -- the fact that removing a grounding wire stopped the tripping is telling you that something *else* is wrong, and removing the grounding wire is simply masking the symptoms of that other fault

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  It merely provides a hack that leaves the circuit in a dangerous state.

Comment: I guess that _this_ is what Harper means when he says "you'll keep experimenting until you find something that works, but that something _could kill you_". The ground wire is meant to provide _life protecting safety_. Having a circuit that only works when this safety is removed indicates that _something_ is terribly wrong somewhere else.